# Lights stop working on only some even when component is the same

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I'm trying to make lights in Unity for my house.

I've got 14 lights in my house, however, there is a small problem. This is because the lights are dimmed in some parts of the house and not in others. I have checked that all of the light components are the same (they are), and sometimes I get this flickering thing? I have wondered if it is because something isn't done correctly, like baking the house or whatnot.

Here is the light component:

[image: light component]

Here is what the lights look like (they are red because I thought it would be easier to see):

[image: What the lights look like]

As you can see, the lights just stop working as shown by the line

If anyone can help me that would be great!

Edit:
Rendering in Quality:

[image: Rendering quality]

Comment: maybe some inverted normal?

Comment: Check lighting settings in Project Settings/Quality/Rendering in legacy, or RenderPipelineAsset/Lighting in URP. Maybe your Pixel Light Count/Per Object Limit is low.

Comment: @derHugo i don't think it would be an inverted normal, i downloaded the house from sketchfab, and there aren't any parts that you can see through (except the windows ;) )

Comment: @h4ri image added to the question

Comment: depending on the shader that is used it could still be the case ;) Since it is such a sharp line it has to do something with the mesh itself rather than light settings ... is this a new GameObject? or does it all belong to the same mesh?

Comment: Are you reaching a light limit?  What happens if you disable all lights except that one?

Comment: so i was just fiddling with the lights and made the render mode set to 'Important' before it was 'Auto' now it seems to be fixed. @derHugo it is multiple meshes,

Comment: You're probably running into the light count limit. You should consider baking them.

Comment: @Voidsay I changed the render mode to 'Important' and that stopped it. also, nothing in my scene is baked,

Comment: @Jerry Keep in mind that setting a light to important forces it to render with "per-pixel" quality, which is heavy on performance. Don't make a habit of applying it to everything.

Comment: @Voidsay then what would I do if it is so taxing?

Comment: @Jerry You can [bake the lightmaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lightmapping.html) for your environment. You get better lighting with a great performance on weak devices, but it can take a while to render on your developer machine and it doesn't do shadows for dynamic objects, for obvious reasons.

Comment: if I bake the light maps, it will make the dynamic objects (which I'm assuming are the ones that can move around) won't have shadows, how would I make them not flicker, and still cast shadows on the dynamic objects? without rendering the lights as 'Important'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having too many lights rendering at one time affects how the lights are showing. In order to make them look the same, I needed to make something that will turn lights off. I did this by creating a "fuse box" that has a max amount of light groups that are allowed to be turned on, if the amount of groups that are on is higher than the max it turns them all off.

Code to turn off the lights:

```
void ShutDown()
{
    if (!shutOff)
    {
        foreach (Light l in lights[index].lightGroups)
        {
            l.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else!

:)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar effect in my game, I think could be due to many lights on scene, you have to set some lights to important so that they never flicker even if resources are going down, so aside from doing this other thing could be just baking lights yes, and this way they wont flicker but of course that makes it no real time so depends on your needs

Here its explained about how to set light important level

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Light.html

Comment: I have made my lights rendering 'Important' but another user said that doing this is heavy on performance, so although it is good for right now, I want to know how to set something up so it is good for further on. If you know what I mean

Comment: I would say the best is use baked lights then, unless you have to turn then on and off or move them. Baked lights eat not much resources, it can take a while to be baked but its worth that because later in game it makes the fps a lot better. Also if you add light probes it will improve the effect but depends on your personal likes. Ah and I would suggest you turn auto bake to off because else it could be baking with every change you make and maybe at some point you make a lot but only want to bake in the end once

Comment: The lights that I have been talking about on this question are ones that can be turned off and on, like a house. So i don't know if baking them would work

Comment: In that case then it wont work I think, baking lights is for lights that will not change in runtime I believe, my suggestion is see if you can disable shadows on some light here and there or reduce detail in shadows, make them not smooth and so on, maybe decrease the distance they are affecting and also reduce the number of bounce in lighting tab, just what comes to my mind about this issue that has worked for me. Also you can set the ambient light/color so that way maybe you dont need as many lights

Comment: I've got the shadows to hard,

Comment: It usually happens that, like shadows look harder when its optimized, you have to find the right balance for you through trial and error. Try to see if some lights could alwas be on to bake them maybe or use directional light to fake some light too, well its complex issue as it tends to eat lot of resources when it starts looking better

Comment: All of the lights are able to be turned on and off, so I don't think the baking one would work. How would I do directional lights?

Comment: Sorry I couldnt get back before. I see what you mean, and in terms of directional light I mean well, if you have several lights that kind of point in the same direction and maybe you can turn them on/off together then maybe a directional light could work on that somehow but I know it wont look the same as several individual points. My personal bet in this case would be like manually hide with code the lights that are not in your current sight, I mean, if you are in a room and you cant see 2 rooms away from yours then you can disable these light with code and maybe save some resources

Comment: That would be like baking the gameObjects that i have the lights attached to and using the occlusion culling?

Comment: Well, you could use oclusion culling yes, but I tend to do it by my own code, I mean, just measure distance from your camera to the lights and hide these that are really far, or if your level structure is like having many walls and door in middle then think to group the lights per room or so and hide these that are in other room different than your current on, I think it could be a trial and error work with this method but you could do something this way

Comment: I could start with all of the lights off and the player has to turn them on themselves and then if there is too many on there would be a fuse box that would "trip" and the player has to turn it back on

Comment: Yes, good idea,  that way it could work well I think, the thing is to keep only some lights at same time, this way they wont flicker or do strange things

Comment: Sounds good, what should I mark as correct?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I didnt notice it, well I hope this has worked for you, and as for what is correct, its up to you, thanks for your will to help as well